# How do I use a variable from a Const in a useEffect hook? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filtering, use-effect

**EDIT**: Your solution worked but now my dropdown doesn't show what is selected unless its selected twice, like this:

[Here I selected Health Care, but the dropdown still says "Select Industry"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYJUz.png)

[The here I selected Health Care for a second time and it now shows that it is selected, this is happening with all of the dropdown options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtAWo.png)

---

I have a dropdown menu that I can select an option from, which saves the option to a variable. I want to use this variable to change the fetch route used in my useEffect hook so that the data found is filtered to a specific industry. How would I do this? Is there an easier way to filter the mapped data rather than changing the fetch address?

This is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"; 


// Data Table
export default function Table() {

    const[rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

    const columns = [
        { headerName: "Name", field: "name", sortable: true},
        { headerName: "Symbol", field: "symbol", sortable: true},
        { headerName: "Industry", field: "industry", sortable: true},
    ];

    const searchIndustry = (event, {value}) => {
      let industryChoice = value;
      // I want to use this variable 
      console.log(industryChoice);
    }

    const DropdownSearchSelection = () => (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Industry"
        search
        selection
        options={industryOptions}
        onChange={searchIndustry}
      />
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      // To change this address
        fetch(`http://131.181.190.87:3000/stocks/symbols${industryChoice}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => 
            data.map(stock => {
                return {
                    name: stock.name,
                    symbol: stock.symbol,
                    industry: stock.industry,
                };
            })
        )
        .then(stock => setRowData(stock));
    }, []);

    const industryOptions = [
        { key: "as", value: "", text: "View All Industries" },
        { key: "dc", value: "?industry=consumer%20discretionary", text: "Consumer Discretionary" },
        { key: "ds", value: "?industry=consumer%20staples", text: "Consumer Staples" },
        { key: "en", value: "?industry=energy", text: "Energy" },
        { key: "fi", value: "?industry=einancials", text: "Financials" },
        { key: "hc", value: "?industry=health%20care", text: "Health Care" },
        { key: "in", value: "?industry=industrials", text: "Industrials" },
        { key: "it", value: "?industry=information%20technology", text: "Information Technology" },
        { key: "ma", value: "?industry=materials", text: "Materials" },
        { key: "re", value: "?industry=real%20estate", text: "Real Estate" },
        { key: "ts", value: "?industry=telecommunication%20services", text: "Telecommunication Services" },
        { key: "ut", value: "?industry=utilities", text: "Utilities" },
      ];

  return (
    <div className="filter">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Filter..."/>
            <DropdownSearchSelection />
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div className="ag-theme-balham" >
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={columns}
                rowData={rowData}
                pagination={true}
                paginationPageSize={11}
            />
        </div>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I would call `setState` for each dropdown onChange, then in your include the state in your `useEffect`'s dependencies array list. Also I will probably use `query-string` package to parse the query string so the code will be more clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to store the selected option from `Dropdown` into your component's state.

```
const[industryChoice, setIndustryChoice] = useState();
```

And on your `searchIndustry` method,

```
const searchIndustry = (event, {value}) => {
  setIndustryChoice(value);
}
```

And then, you add `searchIndustry` as part of the dependency array, which will fetch the data based on the `industryChoice` state, and this will be triggered whenever the value of `industryChoice` is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // To change this address
    fetch(`http://131.181.190.87:3000/stocks/symbols${industryChoice}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
        data.map(stock => {
            return {
                name: stock.name,
                symbol: stock.symbol,
                industry: stock.industry,
            };
        })
    )
    .then(stock => setRowData(stock));
}, [industryChoice]);
```

As for the additional issue you have raised, you should bind the value of the `industryChoice` state to the `Dropdown`.

```
<Dropdown
   placeholder="Select Industry"
   search
   selection
   options={industryOptions}
   onChange={searchIndustry}
   value={industryChoice}
/>
```

Comment: Since doing this my dropdown menu now doesn't show what's selected unless its selected twice (I believe its because of onChange), any suggestions on how to fix that??

Comment: You mean you have to click twice every single time?

Comment: Yeah, like the page changes correctly, but the dropdown doesn't tell you what you have selected unless you select it twice, if that makes sense. I wish I could upload a video or something.

Comment: I edited my original question so now you should be able to see screenshots of my problem :)

Comment: Hmm.. For the first issue, have you tried binding the state to the value of the dropdown? Let me include the sample on my answer